# Why does a ulimit -u far greater than the number of processes I'm running cause problems?

Tags: ulimit

I'm running 200 processes, but a `ulimit -u` of 400 seems to cause some problem:

```
$ ps -A | wc -l
199
$ ulimit -u 400
zsh: fork failed: resource temporarily unavailable
```

I'm confused. Why is the limit being hit?

**edit**: Initially `ulimit -u` gives

```
$ ulimit -u
47334
```

Comment: That's unusual; `ulimit` is a built-in command, so will not cause a fork. Does this happen under `zsh -f`? That is, is there something in your shell configuration that forksalot?

Comment: So you get that error right after changing `ulimit`?  Does it do that for any (higher) limit?

Comment: Are you running java or other multi-threaded code?

Comment: @thrig The thing that is forking is a command that is part of my shell prompt.

Comment: @StephenHarris Yes there are multi-threaded  programs running

Comment: @JuliePelletier A limit of 500 seems to be fine

Comment: I just don't get how running the `ulimit -u 200` can give that error unless the limit is already reached before that call.

Comment: Note that production systems should not normally use `ulimit` for control as it may cause very undesired side-effects.

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're trying to solve by limiting the number of processes?  If you guess wrong the upper limit you can cripple your system much worse than you did above (think corrupted filesystems).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Linux *threads* count towards the `ulimit -u` count, but they don't show up normally with `ps -A`.  You need to add the `L` flag.

eg on my machine:

```
% ps -A | wc -l 
124
% ps -AL | wc -l
155
```

We can see there's 31 more processes running; these are threads, normally hidden from view.

With java and other highly threaded applications it can be easy to run more threads/processes than you think.  Your `ulimit -u` value needs to take this into account.

This can unexpectedly hit people running a lot of java applications on RedHat systems where it comes, by default, with a `ulimit` setting:

```
% cat /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf 
# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent
# accidental fork bombs.
# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.

*          soft    nproc     4096
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```